# Draw a trace of prolog

Tags: prolog

I am learning to use prolog with lists and apply the trace command and draw the paper trace myself, but I do not understand very well how the debug does it with the lists (without lists if it is). I have the following example program.

```
p([X],X). 
p([X|L],Y):-p(L,Y). 
q([X,X]).
```

and I apply the query

```
p(V,2),q(V).
```

and what I get the baby for console is this

```
Call: (9) p(_612, 2) ? creep
Exit: (9) p([2], 2) ? creep
Call: (9) q([2]) ? creep
Fail: (9) q([2]) ? creep
Redo: (9) p(_612, 2) ? creep
Call: (10) p(_902, 2) ? creep
Exit: (10) p([2], 2) ? creep
Exit: (9) p([_900, 2], 2) ? creep
Call: (9) q([_900, 2]) ? creep
Exit: (9) q([2, 2]) ? creep
V = [2, 2] ;
```

and then a loop to infinity, but that does not matter to me because I do not know how to get the solution of V = [2, 2];

Making the appropriate substitutions so that they unify I obtain for the literal p (V, 2)

```
[X] = L
2 = X
[X | L] = V
[2 | L] = V
```

So what I want is to know the value of V, so I would have [2, [2]] and that can be translated into [2, 2]?

Then I would have to check it for the second literal q (V) that unifies, so it is a valid solution. Would this be your reasoning?

Comment: the title of your question is completely different from the content of the question. You should improve that so that we are clear what is the question. By the way the question itself is not clear: what exactly are you asking? :)

Comment: @VictorNoël How to draw a trace of prolog and give the solutions. I have those facts and rules and I want to draw the trace with the solutions and I have put the substitutions that I have obtained so that it unifies and all that and it gives me that. In the end I put that. If you think there is something wrong, you can edit without problem, I do not find anything wrong